# Override JHtml (HTMLHelper) class methods

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, overrides, jhtml

I'm developing a custom Joomla template and have `unset` a lot of the core dependencies, such as jQuery and Bootstrap in the template's `index.php`.

The problem now is that the core extensions call some of Bootstrap's featuues, like so:

```
JHtml::_('tooltip', $tooltip, $options);
```

which in turn calls the Bootstrap library and the `unset` doesn't work as it tried to remove the file before it's called.

So I'd like to override some of the methods for the `JHtmlBootstrap` class, so that they return nothing, like so:

```
abstract class JHtmlBootstrap
{
    public static function tooltip() {
        return;
    }
}
```

I know I'm going to have to write a plugin, but not sure as to the best approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a system plugin and use `JHtml::register()` to register your custom methods.

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper;
use Joomla\CMS\Plugin\CMSPlugin;

class PlgSystemExample extends CMSPlugin
{
    public function onAfterInitialise()
    {
        HTMLHelper::register('bootstrap.tooltip', array(__CLASS__, 'noTooltips'));
    }

    public static function noTooltips()
    {
    }
}
```